# How do i find all the api's exposed on WSO2 EMM

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

is there any other route other than the route mentioned in another post (pasted the post details below), where need to look into a bunch of files and understand the api's exposed.

=====

Yes its possible. All the functions in EMM are exposed as APIs. You better look at the scripts at wso2emm-1.1.0\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\emm\api to get an idea on the APIs in EMM. You can find the endpoints inside those js filese. Also please note that this app is written using JaggeryJS. For the authentication you may look at SAML sso which has been used in EMM. For this you could use a modal dialog to load the SSO page or else you may modify it to support OAuth as follows.

Comment: I am looking for api's to register a device. To be more specific a device other then android or ios.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 EMM does not expose any APIs, that supports registering a device other than Android or iOS as they are the supported platforms. The quoted text is from a question related to iOS.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I saw couple of webinars and its mentioned that EMM can be used manage iot devices, that is the reason i was trying it out.

Comment: Proper IoT support is coming on the next version of EMM, this will be available in few more months.